# Why is numpy's root failing?

Tags: python, numpy, polynomial-math, polynomials

- *Why is my answer from [`np.roots`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roots.html) different from [`np.polynomial.polynomial.polyroots`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyroots.html)?*

Define the polynomial

```
# a specific polynomial x**0 + x**1 + x**2 + x**3
p = [1, -2.8176255165067872, -0.97639120853458261, -0.86023870029448335]
```

Here is a neat example to demonstrate the difference,

```
import numpy as np
r1 = np.roots(p); r2 = np.polynomial.polynomial.polyroots(p)
f = lambda x: np.sum([x**i*j for i,j in enumerate(p)])

print "{:>10} {:>10}".format("roots","polyroots")
for i,j in zip(r1, r2): # test should return 0
    print "{:10.5f} {:10.5f}".format(np.abs(f(i)),np.abs(f(j)))
```

The output is clearly not zero

```
     roots  polyroots
  46.41221    0.00000
   1.97595    0.00000
   1.97595    0.00000
```

### Correct Case for Comparison

In comparision, Mathematica correctly obtains the roots:

```
fn[x_] := 1.` - 2.817625516506788` x - 0.97639120853458261` x^2 - 0.8602387002944835` x^3
Roots[fn[x] == 0, x]
```

which provides the roots as:

```
x == -0.723475 - 1.78978 I || x == -0.723475 + 1.78978 I || x == 0.311926
```

Testing verifies this:

```
fn[-0.7234748700272414` - 1.7897835665374093` I]
-4.44089*10^-16 - 2.66454*10^-15
```

Comment: as a side comment: `p = [1, -2.8176255165067872, 2.6797211079532777, -0.86023870029448335]` gives a *decent* answer for `np.root`

Comment: It appears as thought the `numpy` documentation is incorrect. `np.roots` requires the `reversed()` array as an input

Comment: You're right that `np.roots` requires a reversed array -- but I think that the documentation is completely accurate in this regard...

Comment: @mgilson you're totally correct. Looking carefully the docs are correct. I've spent an hour reading them incorrectly !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code in `numpy.polynomial` is newer than `numpy.roots` (and `numpy.poly1d`, etc).  In the new polynomial code, the convention for the order of the coefficients was changed.  In the new code, the coefficients are given in increasing order, while in the old code, the highest order coefficient is given first.

```
In [98]: p = [1, -2.8176255165067872, -0.97639120853458261, -0.86023870029448335]

In [99]: np.roots(p[::-1])
Out[99]: array([-0.72347487+1.78978357j, -0.72347487-1.78978357j,  0.31192616+0.j        ])

In [100]: np.polynomial.polynomial.polyroots(p)
Out[100]: array([-0.72347487-1.78978357j, -0.72347487+1.78978357j,  0.31192616+0.j        ])
```

Comment: nice one Warren. We got there at about the same time, which is impressive since I had a whole one hour head start :)

Comment: That documentation looks correct to me.  What problem do you see?

Comment: I think it is a case of reading what I expect to see rather than what is actually there. I take it that the `polynomial` variant is the one that should be used as it seems to be more accurate

Comment: I haven't heard that the code in the `polynomial` module is more accurate, but I'm not saying it isn't.  That might be a question for the numpy mailing list.